# Javascript regexp.test() .NET equivalent

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, equivalent

How can I do the following in C# :

```
var re = /^\d{4}(\/\d{2}){2} \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}$/;
re.test('2013/03/05 15:22:00'); // returns true
```

Comment: You have not asked a question... However, you probably want to look at the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class. Having said that, you might be better looking at the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) method.

Comment: OBTW, there's no _exact_ equivalent because C#, unlike JavaScript, has no support for regular expressions. That support is in the .NET Framework.

Comment: What do you want me to do? Just reformulate the title?

Comment: An detailed explanation of what you were expecting would be useful to me and really apreciated. Thanks...

Comment: I understood exactly what the OP was asking, even before the edits. The answers helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code should get you where you want to be.

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\d{4}(\/\d{2}){2} \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}$");
String test = "2013/03/05 15:22:00";

if (rx.IsMatch(test))
{
    //Test String matches
}
else
{
    //Test String does not match
}
```

Comment: Whoops.. Looks like Davin got it while I was typing it up.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Regex.IsMatch` instead ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx)).

```
Regex.IsMatch("2013/03/05 15:22:00", @"^\d{4}(\/\d{2}){2} \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}$"); // true if match
```

Comment: @KristerRenaud Thanks, I was unsure about that beginning forward slash!